# How do I Evaluate the Integral $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{x^2}+1} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

Like the question states, how do I evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{x^2}+1} \, dx$$
I know of no methods to evaluate this, but when I plug this into Mathematica and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F(1%20%2B%20E%5Ex%5E2),%20%7Bx,%20-Infinity,%20Infinity%7D%5D), it returns 
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{x^2}+1} \, dx=\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{\pi } \zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
where $\zeta (x)$ is the Riemann Zeta Function.

Comment: One idea is to try to use $\frac{1}{e^{x^2}+1} = \frac{1}{e^{x^2}}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x^2}} = y(1-y+y^2-\ldots)$ where $y = e^{-x^2}$ and integrate term by term using the known result for the gaussian integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} = \sqrt{\pi/a}$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Comment: @Winther oh, so that's where the $\zeta\left(\dfrac12\right)$ comes from...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given integral equals
$$ 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+e^{x^2}} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}(1+e^{z})}=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nz}}{\sqrt{z}}\,dz $$
or
$$ \sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\pi}\,\eta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=(1-\sqrt{2})\sqrt{\pi}\,\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $$
as claimed by WA.